# How to get a memory footprint of a PySpark job during execution?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using the following code to calculate the memory footprint of a PySpark job:

```
catalyst_plan = data_frame._jdf.queryExecution().logical()
df_size = spark_session._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(catalyst_plan).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()
```

`df_size` if the occupied by the Dataframe when data is loaded.
I don't like this approach because some protected methods (`_jdf`, `_jsparkSession`) are used and the whole solution is not standard.

Is there a way to get the size of the loaded Spark data frame using "standard" approach? By standard, I mean some approach which is considered official, not hacky (for example, via public methods, or using Dataproc API).

Comment: have you tried memory profiler here, does this help with your use case https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/development/debugging.html#profiling-memory-usage-memory-profiler

Comment: @BihagKashikar not yet. Thank you for pointing out to this tool.

Comment: hope you find this useful :-)